# No arm64 support for openjdk-17-jdk?

Tags: 20.04

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openjdk-11-jdk supports multiple architectures including arm64. https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openjdk-17-jdk does not seem to support arm64. What could be reason ? Is there a plan to support more architectures for openjdk-17-jdk ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled the `focal-updates` pocket in the `universe` repo, you'll see that the package also supports ARM.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/openjdk-17-jdk

This means your `/etc/apt/sources.conf` must include this line:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
```